# WinAPI with RawInput - key strokes are not sent to other windows in the same app

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I have created WinAPI windows for my rendering application. I am using raw input for keyboard and mouse.

The problem is, I have added 3rd party GUI to get inputs from user (like load models etc.). Mouse is working (I can click on buttons etc.), but keyboard not. If I put focus on edit box and start writing, nothing appears and key strokes are lost in focused GUI. However, the main window is still processing them and e.g. camera is moving around.

If I click into some other window, like web browser, all is behaving as it should.

My WinAPI window is inited like this:

```
bool Form::InitWnd(HINSTANCE instance){
    WNDCLASS window_class;

    window_class.style          = CS_OWNDC;
    window_class.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    window_class.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    window_class.hInstance      = instance;
    window_class.hIcon          = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    window_class.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    window_class.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    window_class.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    window_class.lpszClassName  = this->name.c_str();
    window_class.lpfnWndProc    = &Form::MainWndProc;

    if (!RegisterClass(&window_class)) return false;        

    this->mainWindowHandle = CreateWindow(this->name.c_str(),
        L"Caption", //caption
        this->style,    //style flags
        this->positionX,    //x pos
        this->positionY, //y pos
        this->width,
        this->height,
        NULL, //parent window
        NULL, //menu
        this->instance,
        this); //pointer to window creation data

    if (this->mainWindowHandle == 0) return false;

    this->engineCore->InitWindow(this->mainWindowHandle);
    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Form::MainWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    static Form* me = 0;

    switch ( msg ){
        case WM_CREATE:
            me = (Form*)((CREATESTRUCT*)lParam)->lpCreateParams;
            return 0;           
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;           
        case WM_INPUT:
            if (me) me->engineCore->UpdateInput(lParam);
            break;          
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);    
}

int Form::Run(int cmd){ 

    ShowWindow(this->mainWindowHandle, cmd);
    UpdateWindow(this->mainWindowHandle);

    MSG msg = {0};

    while ( true ){
        if ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) ){
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;              
            else {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }       
        else {
            engineCore->RunMainEngineLoop();
        }    
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

And keyboard is processed:

//Register

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];

Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01; 
Rid[0].usUsage = DEVICE_KEYBOARD; 
Rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_NOLEGACY;                                    
Rid[0].hwndTarget = windowHandle;

if (RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, count, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE){
    MY_LOG_ERROR("Failed to register device");
}
```

//Update loop

```
UINT dwSize;
GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

BYTE * lpb = new BYTE[dwSize];
if (lpb == NULL){
    return 0;
}

if (GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) != dwSize){     
    SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(lpb);
    return 0;
}

RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)lpb;

if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD){
   //process keys
}

SAFE_DELETE_ARRAY(lpb);
```

Similar code is used for mouse

Comment: If you want input to go through the normal messages-routed-to-focused-window logic, then don't use Raw Input API.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem is I need both... Raw input is used in OpenGL rendering window. The only solution would be to disable raw input, if focus is somewhere else. But I dont know, how to possibly detect lost / gain of focus...

Comment: It sounds like you should not set the RIDEV_NOLEGACY flag.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645565(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Martin: You should receive `WM_SETFOCUS` and `WM_KILLFOCUS` messages for the window hosting the OpenGL context.  You can also check for `WM_ACTIVATE` at the top-level window which is an ancestor of the window hosting OpenGL (if your conventional controls are inside a different top-level window).

Comment: @thanks.. solved the problem. Can you post it as answer?